# DiscordJS - "p1choice" variable changes its value by itself for no reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So im (re)coding rps command for my discord bot, and there r 2 declarations that define results of a match at end of a game (that "end" isn't coded yet cuz i noticed that glitch and added some debugging lines and tried to fix it). Anyway, those 2 declarations are p1choice and p2choice, and they store choices of players. You can see in code where did i add console.log(), and when i run a command and use buttons (the code i provided r listeners for buttons) i get this in my console:

rock // this is value of p1choice at the beginning
undefined // this is value of p1choice that changes to undefined for no reason
rock // this is value of p2choice

and interaction.reply() returns 'rock ; undefined' just to make it clear

why is it like that?

This is the code:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async(interaction) => {
    
    let p1choice;
    let p2choice;

    if (interaction.customId == 'rps-join') {

        const embeds = interaction.message.embeds;
      
        if (embeds && embeds.length > 0) {
            const mentionRegex = /<@!?(?<userId>\d+)>/;
            const match = mentionRegex.exec(embeds[0].description);
      
            if (match && match.groups.userId) {
                const userId = match.groups.userId;
                var mentionedMember = interaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(userId); // Player who started a match
            };
        };

        if(mentionedMember.user.id == interaction.user.id) return interaction.reply({content: `:negative_squared_cross_mark: You can't join this match!`, ephemeral: true});
        if(!interaction.message.mentions.members.first().user.id == interaction.user.id) return interaction.reply({content: `:negative_squared_cross_mark: You can't join this match!`, ephemeral: true });

        /**Round 0 - Player1 is choosing */

        const startButtons = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('rps-rock1')
                    .setLabel('Rock')
                    .setEmoji('1109128025628491826')
                    .setStyle('SECONDARY'),
                
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('rps-paper1')
                    .setLabel('Paper')
                    .setEmoji('1109128023741055016')
                    .setStyle('SECONDARY'),

                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('rps-scissors1')
                    .setLabel('Scissors')
                    .setEmoji('1109128021526466661')
                    .setStyle('SECONDARY')
            );

        const startEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('ROCK-PAPER-SCISSORS :video_game:')
            .setDescription(`${interaction.user} has accepted the challange! :fire:`)
            .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Match Details', value: 
                `${codeBlock(`[P1] ${mentionedMember.user.username}: Is choosing now... \n[P2] ${interaction.user.username}: Didn't choose yet...`)}`}
            )
            .setColor('BLUE')
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter({text: `Requested by ${mentionedMember.user.tag}`, iconURL: mentionedMember.user.displayAvatarURL()});

            interaction.message.delete();
            interaction.reply({embeds: [startEmbed], components: [startButtons]});
    };

    if(interaction.customId == 'rps-rock1' || interaction.customId == 'rps-paper1' || interaction.customId == 'rps-scissors1') {

        const embeds = interaction.message.embeds;
      
        if (embeds && embeds.length > 0) {
            const mentionRegex = /<@!?(?<userId>\d+)>/;
            const match = mentionRegex.exec(embeds[0].description);
      
            if (match && match.groups.userId) {
                const userId = match.groups.userId;
                var mentionedMemberR2 = interaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(userId); // Player who accepted the match
            };
        };

        /** Round 1  - Player2 is choosing*/

        if(interaction.customId == 'rps-rock1') { p1choice = 'rock'; console.log(p1choice) } else
        if(interaction.customId == 'rps-paper1') { p1choice = 'paper' } else
        if(interaction.customId == 'rps-scissors1') { p1choice = 'scissors' };
        
        const firstRoundEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('ROCK-PAPER-SCISSORS :video_game:')
            .setDescription(`${interaction.user} has made a choice!`)
            .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Match Details', value: 
                `${codeBlock(`[P1] ${interaction.user.username}: Has made a choice... \n[P2] ${mentionedMemberR2.user.username}: Is choosing now...`)}`}
            )
            .setColor('BLUE')
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter({text: `Requested by ${interaction.user.tag}`, iconURL: interaction.user.displayAvatarURL()});

        const firstRoundButtons = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('rps-rock2')
                    .setLabel('Rock')
                    .setEmoji('1109128025628491826')
                    .setStyle('SECONDARY'),
            
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('rps-paper2')
                    .setLabel('Paper')
                    .setEmoji('1109128023741055016')
                    .setStyle('SECONDARY'),

                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('rps-scissors2')
                    .setLabel('Scissors')
                    .setEmoji('1109128021526466661')
                    .setStyle('SECONDARY')
            );

        interaction.message.delete();
        interaction.reply({embeds: [firstRoundEmbed], components: [firstRoundButtons]});
    };

    /** Round 2 aka finish */

    if(interaction.customId == 'rps-rock2' || interaction.customId == 'rps-paper2' || interaction.customId == 'rps-scissors2') {

        const embeds = interaction.message.embeds;
      
        if (embeds && embeds.length > 0) {
            const mentionRegex = /<@!?(?<userId>\d+)>/;
            const match = mentionRegex.exec(embeds[0].description);
      
            if (match && match.groups.userId) {
                const userId = match.groups.userId;
                var mentionedMemberR3 = interaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(userId); // Player who started the match
            };
        };

        console.log(p1choice);

        if(interaction.customId == 'rps-rock2') { p2choice = 'rock'; console.log(p2choice) } else
        if(interaction.customId == 'rps-paper2') { p2choice = 'paper' } else
        if(interaction.customId == 'rps-scissors2') { p2choice = 'scissors' };

        interaction.reply(`${p1choice} ; ${p2choice}`)
   };


});
```